# How to get users time based on location in wordpress or in php and they will see the time base on location in the website

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a online radio station with wordpress.so i want that when a user browsing this site from usa he will see the program schedule based on his time.means i want user can see program schedule based on their time.so how can i do it in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to PHP script (ajax, cookie, etc) local user time using JS, for ex.:

```
var now = new Date();
```

when you will know user local timezone you can use appropriate time offset in your php code/ mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

Put timestamp of time in question (**in GMT**) like this:

```html
<span data-timestamp='1466842876'></span>
```

Then JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
    $('[data-timestamp]').each(function ()
    {
        $(this).text(local_time($(this).attr('data-timestamp')));
    });
    function local_time(UNIX_timestamp)
    {
        var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
        var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
        return ((a.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + a.getDate() : a.getDate()) + ' ' + months[a.getMonth()] + ' ' + a.getFullYear() + ' ' + ((a.getHours() < 10) ? '0' + a.getHours() : a.getHours()) + ':' + ((a.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + a.getMinutes() : a.getMinutes()) + ':' + ((a.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + a.getSeconds() : a.getSeconds());
    }
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93ov5yt1/1/)

Comment: @Md.Mahedihasan well, GMT is UTC+0 so pretty much same thing. This will work for you